# jquery ui Drag&drop effect

Tags: css, jquery-ui-draggable

Lets say I have a div #elements with a ul inside.The div has position: absolute and is on top of the body element.When the user drags an li element from #elements ul a clone should be made that is on top of the body and the #elements div and listen to when it is dragged over the body.How can I achieve this effect?
P.S:the clone should be on top of #elements when dragged.

html:

```
<body>
<div id="elements">
   <ul>
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
   </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#elements {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:100px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, it may help:

[Drag and Drop for Touch and none-touch devices](http://blog.freelancer-id.com/2012/01/23/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-for-touch-devices/)